# How to catch correct value in conditional in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements, javascript-objects

```
const [
  MessageListDataProvider,
  useMessageListData
] = constate(() => {
  const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState({})

  const [messagePath, useMessagePath] = useState(api.UNRESOLVED_MESSAGES_PATH)
  const getMessagePath = (newPath) => {
    useMessagePath(newPath)
  }
  const {
    value,
    loading,
    error,
    retry: refresh
  } = useAsyncRetry(async () => {
    return api.fetchAllMessages(messagePath)
  }, [messagePath])

   if (value !== undefined) {
    console.log('value.messages', value.messages.length)
    if (!newValue[messagePath]) {
      console.log('newValue in conditional', newValue)
      setNewValue(oldObj => ({ ...newValue, [messagePath] : value.messages }))
    } 
  }
  console.log('newValue', newValue)
  return {
    newValue,
    getMessagePath,
    value,
    loading,
    error,
    refresh
  }
})
```

I am trying to store specific values from an API call in a separate object based different keys.

example:

```
newValue : {
    `/messages?limit=100&offset=0`: [{}, {}, {}],
    `/messages?status=Unresolved&limit=100&offset=0`: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}],
}
```

Strangely, the key gets updated and added but not the array value???!

See below...

[image]

Any idea how I can—for a lack of a better idea "catch" that API array value?

Comment: If you can post the JSON template and the expected result, It will be helpful. Or a code sandbox with a dummy data can also be fine

Comment: I am almost certain you should be using a `useEffect` for those `if (value) & if (newValue)` checks.